# pycharm is unable to load icon.ico file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, icons

I have written this code:

```
from plyer import notification
import time

def notifier():
    while True:
        notification.notify(
            title="Take a break",
            message="""It's been 20 minutes
Take a break
Take care of your eyes
            """,
            app_icon=r"C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\myprojects\icon.ico",
            timeout=10
        )
        time.sleep(20*60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    notifier()
```

Every time I run this it's showing:

```
Could not load icon C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\myprojects\icon.ico
```

Comment: Which filetypes does notify/plyer support?

Comment: First of all please show the full error, second make sure there is an `icon.ico` in that specific path

Comment: Yes, there is an icon.ico file

Comment: Is there any chance that icon.ico is just a JPG or PNG that has been renamed, rather than a genuine ICO format file?

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this picture is converted into `.ico` by a converter, and not by simply renaming it while saving it to a PC.
Also, double-check the path and name.